# VS.Net on Windows 8 OS

Tags: windows-8, vb.net

Is it possible to install VS2003 on Windows 8. Will there be any problems in setting up? If anyone has done or know about his please reply.

Comment: To state the obvious why not *try* it?

Answer (score 1):

VS.Net 2003 uses [.net 1.1 which is no longer supported since Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2489698/en-us). So it will likely fail to install. Use a Windows XP Virtual Machine to run this old IDE.